# Curl: sleep/delay between requests

Tags: curl, flurry

I am trying to download flurry exception logs using the following command.

```
curl --cookie ./flurry.jar -k -L "https://dev.flurry.com/exceptionLogsCsv.do?projectID=49999&versionCut=versionsAll&intervalCut=allTime&direction=1&offset=[0-100:10]" --output "exception#1.csv"
```

It works fine and it downloads the csv files based on the offset(10,20,30 etc). I would like to insert a delay between each request. Is it possible to do that in CURL?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using bash shell (Linux) :

```
while :
do
    curl --cookie ./flurry.jar -k -L "https://dev.flurry.com/exceptionLogsCsv.do?projectID=49999&versionCut=versionsAll&intervalCut=allTime&direction=1&offset=[0-100:10]" --output "exception#1.csv"
    sleep 5m
done
```

It is an infinite loop, and the delay is given by the `sleep` command.

**Edit**. On Windows machine, you can do this trick instead :

```
for /L %i in (0,0,0) do (
    curl --cookie ./flurry.jar -k -L "https://dev.flurry.com/exceptionLogsCsv.do?projectID=49999&versionCut=versionsAll&intervalCut=allTime&direction=1&offset=[0-100:10]" --output "exception#1.csv"
    ping -n XX 127.0.0.1>NUL
)
```

The `sleep` command is not available on Windows. But you can use `ping` to "emulate" it. Just replace the XX above with the number of seconds you want to delay.

Comment: I am using windows how can i do it in windows? . also looking at the above code, it seems it will run the same command over and over which is not what i want. The command itself will iterate over as I have offset=[0-100:10] . I would like to mention a delay or sleep i the command,. is it possible?

Comment: To iterate over the offset (10, 20, 30, ..., 100), replace `(0,0,0)` above with `(0,100,10)`. It means start from 0 to 100, increment by 10. But it is not an infinite loop anymore.

Comment: And use the variable %i to the web address. So it will be `...&offset=%i`

Comment: Put the code in a .bat file, and just run the file directly (double-clicking it).

Comment: I don't think the asker wants to re-run `curl` forever; he wants to put delays between successive requests.

Comment: **Warning:** Don't include that `-k` there! That tells cURL NOT to check the certificate! Please see https://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

Answer (score 5):

wget has delay options

```
wget --wait=seconds
```

and also random delay option

```
wget --random-wait
```

Answer (score 4):

in bash, this will pause a random number of seconds in the range 0-60:

```
for d in {0..100..10}
do
    i=`printf "%03d" $d`
    curl --cookie ./flurry.jar -k -L 'https://dev.flurry.com/exceptionLogsCsv.do?projectID=49999&versionCut=versionsAll&intervalCut=allTime&direction=1&offset='$d --output 'exception'$i'.csv'
    sleep $(($RANDOM*60/32767))
done
```

Answer (score 1):

With curl 7.84.0 and later, you can use [request rate limiting](https://everything.curl.dev/usingcurl/transfers/request-rate) with the `--rate` option:

> The request rate is provided as N/U where N is an integer number and U is a time unit. Supported units are s (second), m (minute), h (hour) and d (day, as in a 24 hour unit). The default time unit, if no /U is provided, is number of transfers per hour.

So to wait 10 seconds between each request, use `curl --rate 6/m`.